# File with two consecutive spaces in name fails to compile

Tags: errors

How can I compile a file with two consecutive spaces in the filename? 
The following compiles when named `file name.tex`, but not when named `file{two spaces here}name.tex` (sorry, the editor here converted the two consecutive spaces in the name to a single space, so I had to get creative):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    File name with two spaces fails to compile. 
    \end{document}
```

The error I am getting is:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
>   restricted \write18 enabled.
>   entering extended mode
>   ! I can't find file `"./file name.tex"'.
>   <*> "./file  name.tex"

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I can't change the filename after the fact for unrelated reasons: I am using xr to hyperlink between two documents, and in order for the hyperlinks to work, I can't change the filenames after compilation. Unfortunately, this is for an article I'm submitting to a journal. I'm trying to make the reviewers' life easier by having functioning hyperlinks, but the journal renames the files and the new file names include two consecutive spaces.

Comment: I would say you are out of luck here. It doesn't compile for me on a current texlive and a current miktex neither. pdflatex looks for a file with one space.You could make a bug report at the texlive list. But even if it gets corrected it will probably take some time until new binaries are available. Tell the journal to remove the second space.

Comment: Including several consecutive spaces (or newline chars, while we're at it!) in file names is quite a wicked idea (I know it is not the OP's choice).

Comment: Actually David found a way to compile it: you can try to call the compilation with `pdflatex "file\space\space name"`.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129

Comment: Filenames with *one* space is a wicked idea, with consecutive spaces is more than a disgusting idea.

Comment: Thanks! David Carlisle's solution works for my MWE (though I wish there were also a non-command-line solution). 
For my problem with the hyperlinks, I ended up just manually editing the links in the PDFs (using a simple "find and replace" in a text editor) before David responded here. I'll see if working from the command line also allows me to compile the full doc with the hyperlinks, which would be useful in the future.  If not, I'll post a separate question describing whatever error comes up :-)

Comment: I'd call this a bug - it kept me tied up for an hour today before I realised what was going on, and it applies to xelatex, latexmk and lualatex via latexmk. 

xelatex -no-pdf --shell-escape -recorder  "20210313  FTT cover letter.tex

Gives the error "I can't find file `"20210313 FTT cover letter.tex" and (especially if using a dedicated editor it's a real bummer to figure out that the filename in the error is not the same as the filename in the call).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can input a file with multiple spaces in its name by

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\input{"a\space\space b.tex"}

\end{document}
```

which works as you can see on the terminal

```
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./cc640.aux) (./a  b.tex) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdfte
               >>>12<<<
x/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./cc640.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
```

On the commandline you can use

```
$ tex "a\space\space b"
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=tex)
(./a  b.tex)
```

Comment: Wicked. Really wicked.